# Does cross compiling to Windows from *nix using GCC allow usage of features not yet supported by VC++?

Tags: c++, g++, cross-compiling

I'm looking to build C++ applications for both Windows and *nix. In addition to being able to test that everything compiles fine in a single step, I'm wondering if this actually allows me to use parts of the C++ standard that VC++ does not yet support - such as variadic templates and a few other features.

Would this be possible? Logic seems to dictate that this is so, but I would guess it depends on if gcc needs some windows-specific tool that generates these things as part of the cross compilation stage.

Comment: What is *nix? Is it comparable to unix?

Comment: @stefaanv: '*nix' is an abbreviation used to denote 'various sub-species of Unix, including Linux'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if this actually allows me to use parts of the C++ standard that VC++ does not yet support - such as variadic templates and a few other features.

Yes. What matters for the final executable is  what code the compiler generates or links to, not what VC++ can do.

However, be careful with *platform* specific instructions and methods.

Comment: There's a wholeheckofalot of C++11 that's implemented in the CRT and the standard C++ library.  Not just the compiler.

Comment: @Hans: good to point out - edited to reflect that (as IMO this doesn't affect the "yes" itself)

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, if you write in standard C++, sooner or later VC++ is going to catch up with wathever is missing. Secondly, you are not forced to use VC++ under windows. You can use MinGW which is gcc ported to Windows.

In general, when writing portable software, there are two things you should be aware of:

- Architecture specific operations: To make software portable, you shouldn't rely on a specific architecture. For example, assuming `long int` is 32 bits.
- Operating system operations: This is perhaps more of an issue and harder to handle. If you have an operation that is OS specific, for example creating a directory, you should write your own function for it, inside which you have `#ifdef`s performing different tasks based in which OS they are being compiled on.